# ffmpeg hangs when trying to record video on higher resolutions

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm trying to record some videos using a USB camera, but I'm having some issues when using `ffmpeg`.

If I run `ffmpeg -f video4linux2 -t 00:00:10 -i /dev/video0 out.mpg`, the program tries to record at 640x480 resolution and `ffmpeg` hangs.

However, if I add the `-s` to `ffmpeg` and record at lower resolutions than 640x480 (e.g., 320x240), the video is recorded successfully.

After a hang, if I hit `CTRL+C`, ffmpeg resumes, yielding a file of 0 kB in size. Using `strace` I can see that an `ioctl` call to the device keeps returns `-EINVAL` and subsequent `ioctl`s return `-EAGAIN`.

```
ioctl(3, VIDIOC_G_STD, 0xbe84dfb0)      = -1 EINVAL (Invalid argument)
ioctl(3, VIDIOC_DQBUF, {type=V4L2_BUF_TYPE_VIDEO_CAPTURE}) = -1 EAGAIN (Resource temporarily unavailable)
```

Any ideas why this happens?

I'm using `ffmpeg` version 2.8.7, built through `busybox` 1.25. The host architecture is an ARM processor running kernel 3.2.

I also tried compiling the most recent version from source, and the problem persists...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured out the reason: transcoding and raw data volume.

Using the command line mentioned in my question I was reading from a raw format (yuv422), and transcoding it to mpeg-1, which was the default encoding for my version of `ffmpeg`. The data amount being streamed from the camera was simply too much for the processor, causing the hang. The camera I was using was capable of streaming in a compressed format as well (mjpeg). By switching to this format, `ffmpeg` no longer hanged, and was capable of recording at 15 fps.

However, there was a transcoding step, from mjpeg to mpeg-1. I was able to reach a higher fps count by telling `ffmpeg` to copy the stream, removing the last transcoding step.